# warning: passing argument ’from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]'

Tags: c, pointers, fft

I've been looking around on the other threads somehow related to this, but somehow I just don't get it...

I want to do some FFT on a set of values I have evaluated and wrote this program to first read the values and save them to an array of size `n`.

```
int main () {
    // some variables and also a bit of code to read the 'messwerte.txt'

printf("Geben sie an wieviele Messwerte ausgelesen werden sollen: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
double werte[n]; //Array der "fertigen" Messwerte
in = fopen ("messwerte.txt","r");
double nul[n]; //Array von nullen

int logN = 14;
l=FFT(logN,&werte,&nul);
}
```

In the same file I also do the FFT with the help of this program:

```
double FFT (int logN, double *real, double *im) //logN is base 2 log(N) {
// blabla FFT calculation
}
```

However, when I compile I always get this error:

```
gcc FFT.c -lm
FFT.c: In function ‘main’:
FFT.c:94:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘FFT’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
FFT.c:4:8: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[(unsigned int)(n)]’
FFT.c:94:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘FFT’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
FFT.c:4:8: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[(unsigned int)(n)]’
```

Since this is my first time programming, I really don't know what is wrong with my code. Will I have to set more flags for the compiler or stuff like that (because I had to do this `-lm` stuff or it wouldn't compile and said something like pow not found or so)?

Also I was made aware that there might be a difference when writing on a Windows or a Linux machine, and I am using Linux, Lubuntu 12.10 32-bit if it's a problem of the OS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ```
> l=FFT(logN,&werte,&nul);
>            ^      ^
> ```

Drop ampersands from that line.

---

The problem is that the `&` operator in this context produces an expression with a different type than what `FFT` expects. FFT expects a pointer to a double and `&werte` produces a pointer to an array of N elements. So, in order to make `FFT` happy, just pass `werte` which will quietly decay to a pointer to the first element.

For more information on pointers to arrays, there's a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html).

Comment: It would be nice if you'd add a bit of explanation.

Comment: Thanks alot, problem is gone now, didn't even suppose that someone might answer that fast :D

Answer (score 7):

`werte[]` and `nul[]` are arrays, but the word `werte` itself is an address of the first element of the array. So when you do `&werte` you're trying to pass an address of the address **(as @cnicutar pointed out, this should actually read pointer to an array of N elements)**. SO just pass `werte` and `nul` without the ampersand signs to pass the address of these arrays.

Comment: *when you do &werte you're trying to pass an address of the address* Not really. &werte yields the same address, but with a different type.

Comment: Sorry. Not the address to an address, I was looking for a proper wording for address of the first element in a 2D array (which, as you can see makes little sense in itself). I found the correct way to put it in your answer though. :D